# Comparing cost of living of one state with that of other states

Tags: statistics, wages, living-cost

In the past I read something like this:

> If basic expenses for family went from 100€ to 200€ but its wage
>   went from 200€ to 400€ it can expend more than before.
>
> Weighting the costs of living in state X, in the median wage in state X,
>   is the best way to compare state X's COL with COLs of other states.

I assume that weighting COL in MW particularly is better than weighting COL in average wage (AW), because, although there are few families with extremely high wages, their wages bias AW extremely upwards, while MW is less effected from such extreme cases.

**Is weighting COL in state X in MW in state X the most accurate way to compare that COL to these of other states?**

Comment: "Best" way for what purpose?

Comment: Accuracy, or another answer is that could be a personal purpose - if someone wants to get a good understanding if it is worthy to try to relocate to state X as an expat...

Comment: You should probably read about the state rather than just look at financial indicators...? I am guessing that relocating expats are not really representative of the state's populations, so that will probably cause a distortion.

Comment: @Giskard I personally think just "reading about the state" is at least in some cases not a replacement. Also, I think this assumption on expats is too broad and incorrect but in any case, expats themselves should not be part of the contemplation I ask about.

Comment: You said expats in your explanation...this is pretty much the problem with your question. Purchasing power has different distributions in states. Any aggregation to an average or a median results in information loss. Without knowing your exact purpose, it is impossible to so say which imperfect aggregation is "better".

Comment: I also said personal purpose as if one wants to use this way to calculate COL per hers or his salary and hopefully reach the most accurate result; It could also be a citizen of country X trying to compare its state cost of living with others, but as there are many "purposes" to why desiring to calculate COL, to me discussing here what might be the purpose of whom is honestly seems irrelevant. My question doesn't deal with purchasing power at least directly.

Comment: >>there are many "purposes" to why desiring to calculate COL, to me discussing here what might be the purpose of whom is honestly seems irrelevant.<< This is (in my opinion) a strange statement.

Comment: "My question doesn't deal with purchasing power at least directly." This is just false, you are asking exactly about purchasing power.

Comment: @Giskard It's not false in the sense that purchasing power is not the only reason for a given COL or the only measure to calculate COL.

Comment: So you have specific reasons in mind but refuse to give them? Peculiar.

Comment: @Giskard I explained what I understand to be the most accurate way to compare COL of state X to that of other states and asked if it is indeed as such; besides that I shared possible reasons and for me this is enough and you fail to recognize these data; in suggestion, spare your time and leave this matter.

Comment: Yes, I think that is best for all involved.

Comment: @Giskard if you really think that, you should present reason for that; so far you have presented none.

Comment: Seems to me that by "spare *your* time and leave this matter."  (emphasis by me) you clearly meant that I should leave? Am I misreading this somehow?

Comment: P.s.  I see you have several k reputation in other communities, so you might already know this: If you think I am "trolling" you can flag any trolling comment (there are flag symbols to the left of each comment) and ask for moderator intervention.

Comment: @Giskard I suggested you to leave this matter after mere proving why your comments were useless; replying with suggesting for me to leave "this matter" --- the scoped, precised, fine question I asked, just because it doesn't fit your personal philosophy of "always sharing a purpose" (although I displayed several possible "purposes" in comments) is direct evidence for you being unfit for this community; I wish you worthy punishment in your current life and/or a possible next.

Comment: >>replying with suggesting for me to leave "this matter"<< I did no such thing, I agreed with your suggestion that I leave this matter. Based on this last comment I will stop engaging and will simply suffer in purgatory, that seems preferable. I seriously recommend flagging any comment that you think is rude to you.

Comment: Oh, I thank you dearly for this recommendation sir, it's so kind of you. About "agreeing" with me; that's an utter lie: "Yes, I think that is best for all involved" is your allegedly elegant way to finish the trolling session. I appreciate you for learning from you why I shouldn't suggest anyone from a good will, to spare his time, at least in a similar trolling session.

Comment: I have just read on Wikipedia that you are accusing me of "[sealioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealioning)". Next time you can save time by using this word.

Comment: Or should you save time by saying something like: "I think describing at least one purpose or reason for doing so in the question is a good idea". Trust me, I would only appreciate, but surly not comment.

Comment: My role (as someone coming from the review queue) was to make your question clear. Getting the exact purpose was necessary. Different purposes get different "best" or "most accurate" responses.

Comment: As I have explained, calculating cost of living in a given country is something that could be done from various purposes: A citizen want to calculate its own state's COL and another state's COL for comparison, a tourist who doesn't trust the news media and want to calculate COL by raw data by itself, a potential expat want to do that and someone who just want to know how it is done for general knowledge; I honestly miss how mentioning even one such example would make the question clearer. I want to calculate COL from my own personal reasons. period. someone wants to help? Gladly.

Comment: As I have said, different purposes will yield different "best" or "most accurate" answers. Not sure how I can rephrase this. There are trade-offs. There is probably no state/country that is "best" for everyone.

Comment: Regrading the first sentence, I don't recognize how this would be the case here particularly. Regarding the second phrase: I let anyone do its own contemplation.

Comment: 1. I already expained this in the comments: "Purchasing power has different distributions in states." (In case you wanted clarification, not accusing me of random things would have been better.) 2. Very zen, but probably not a good fit for SE. <--- See, here I am saying that the question is unclear. This is a lot like what you were accusing me of. Though to be honest this is not an offence, SE even has a "close" category for this.

Comment: 1. You didn't explain why it matters for having or not having a most accurate formula that might or might not be the one I described, to measure COL is a given state. 2. Zen has nothing to do with this necessarily and anyway I see no reason to agree. 3. I think you really abuse your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quality of life matters too. This sometimes appears in the labor economics literature as "compensating differential". So it's probably not enough to weight cost of living by median or average wage unless you can objectively determine that all other factors are identical (e.g, tax structure, quality of transportation networks, population density, greenspace, etc.).

These factors are in general not likely to be pecuniary, so they are usually treated as a residual - if MW/COL in state A is less than MW/COL in state B, then the difference must be due to improved amenities in state A.  This is obviously unsatisfactory, and as a result there's a lot of active literature in this area.  And they will, of course, be highly subjective.